# Error: failed to run custom build command for `libc v0.2.139`, but the problem seems deeper

Tags: linux, rust, rust-cargo, libc

I've been going through [the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). I did `cargo new learning` to create the new project. `cargo build` worked and I was able to execute the default "Hello, world!" program no problem, but when I did `cargo run` I get this error:

```
   Compiling learning v0.1.0 (/home/.../rust/learning)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.63s
     Running `target/debug/learning`
error: could not execute process `target/debug/learning` (never executed)

Caused by:
  Invalid argument (os error 22)
```

Which was weird and I couldn't really find a solution to online. So, I decided to just execute the executables manually while I'm still going through the book.

I get to the [guessing game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) chapter. I can get it to accept my input and output it. But as soon as I add

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

to my Cargo.toml and try `cargo build` I get this error:

```
   Compiling libc v0.2.139
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
error: failed to run custom build command for `libc v0.2.139`

Caused by:
  could not execute process >`/home/.../rust/guessing_game/target/debug/build/libc-cef4b0a34c67eecd/build-script-build` (never executed)

Caused by:
  Invalid argument (os error 22)
```

Even after a `cargo clean`

Eventually I get someone to help me. He eventually suggests to run `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./target/debug/build/libc->cef4b0a34c67eecd/build-script-build` which produced this:

```
/build-script-build
cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to get rustc version', /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.139/build.rs:125:17
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6/library/std/src/panicking.rs:607:12
   1: build_script_build::rustc_minor_nightly
             at /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.139/build.rs:125:17
   2: build_script_build::main
             at /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.139/build.rs:9:41
   3: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:251:5
>note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

At this point he suggests I check my path:

```
/home/user/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

And if I run rustc it does a help output and seems to be in my path. The guy who was helping my suggested to reinstall my distro because a few months previous I broke libc and he thought that might fix it. All of this is was reproduced on my new distro after I installed the software I use and updated it.

Looking online finds people with similar errors but it seems for different libraries that they just need to apt install.

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "guessing_game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

Comment: That is a very strange problem. "Invalid argument (os error 22)" means the path is malformed (and not something easy like "not found" or a permission error). I know you probably redacted `/home/.../rust` for a reason but do you have any strange characters in your username or rest of the `...`? That's the only think I can think of.

Comment: Looks like you are on linux, what version of rust are you using, and can you share your Cargo.toml please. You do have to make sure that the 'dev' version of certain systeml ibraries are installed if you are on a debian system.

Comment: It looks like something is preventing executables in your home directory to execute other executables in your home directory. Are you perhaps actively using some security software like apparmor or selinux or firejail or …?

Comment: @kmdreko It is just normal characters, no spaces

Comment: @Caesar Uhh there is probably SELinux preinstalled but haven't done anything with it.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I included my Cargo.toml. I'm not sure what dev packages I would need for the very bare minimum Cargo.toml file being used

Comment: Hm, I might try to reproduce this. What  version of what distro are you using?

Comment: @Caesar Ubuntu Budgie 22.10 https://ubuntubudgie.org/ . After a little bit of digging I found that the folder being on a network share is the issue, somehow. As I would like to keep using the network share this problem still exists, but on a local folder it works as expected. My fstab entry for this mount `//IP/FOLDER /home/USER/FOLDER cifs auto,users,rw,credentials=/home/USER/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev,exec,mfsymlinks 0 0`